# using requirejs for collections of plugins

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using requirejs so that I don't have every single script in the `head` tag for every page. The main motive behind switching to use requirejs is that we have plugins such as CodeMirror, with like 15 plugins to extend that too.

What I want to avoid is having for example:

```
require(["cm", "cmxml", "cmcss", "cmcodefold", "cmfoldgutter", "cmbracefold", "cmcommentfold" ....], fn);
```

I'd like to have this as just `require(["cm"], fn);` and automatically include all of the plugins with this. I'd also like to keep the plugins separate, so combining all the files into CodeMirror.js is not an option.

What I am wondering, before I go creating my own functions or modifying 3rd party code for this, is whether requirejs allows this kind of loading in any case? I have looked at the docs a lot and can't find anything, but that doesn't mean I haven't missed it or that it isn't documented. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm thinking the best way would be to create another CodeMirror script which simply has `require(["cm", "cmcss" ...], fn)` in it. Then I call `require(["cminit"], fn)` (assuming I call my file cminit.js).

Comment: I've managed to get this working using a shim for cminit.js - the `deps` array simply lists CodeMirror and all of the plugins I require for it, and in the Network tab I can see that cminit.js loads last as expected. So I can put all of the code related to CodeMirror in that file (CodeMirror initialisers and event handlers for example). Not sure how much of this is best practice, however, but it works :).

Answer (score 0):

Well I've managed to get this working using a shim for a script called cminit.js - the deps array simply lists all of the plugins for CodeMirror, which in turn have a dependency on CodeMirror which in turn has a dependency on jQuery. So one call to require for cminit.js automagically means that jQuery exists.

It works, but I'm not sure how much of this is best practice. Feel free to comment if you have a better way to do this.